# Want to get Hypen in between numbers

Tags: c#, vb.net, gridview

Hi friends i want to get numbers 123234560 in this pattern 123-23-4560 while bounding the data in the asp .net gridview please help me to do it.

Comment: Can you explain your problem a lot better ?

Comment: can you show us something you have tried so far ?
do want to know how to use String.Insert() function, do have problems with the binding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in c#

```
int i = 123234560;
string strNum = i.ToString("000-000-0000");
Console.WriteLine(strNum);
```

Below is the VB.NET version

```
Dim i As Integer = 123234560
Dim strNum As String = i.ToString("000-000-0000")
Console.WriteLine(strNum)
```

Comment: Incorrect pattern as asked by OP; `i.ToString("000-00-0000");`

Comment: Thanks. Overlooked the last digit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom format in either [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.object.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can also make it as an extension method.

The custom format you need is `"000-00-0000"`, where 0 is a placeholder for any number. If you do an extension method with it, it would look like this :

```
public static string FormatForGridview(this int input)
{
    return string.Format("{0:000-00-0000}", input);
}
```

The equivalent with ToString would be : `input.ToString("000-00-0000");`

and you can use the extension method like this :

```
string numberForGridView = 123234560.FormatForGridview();
```

Answer (score 0):

set the `DataFormatString` with the format

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Number" 
                    HeaderText="Number" 
                    DataFormatString="{0:000-00-0000}" />
```